# Adding token to header using middleware in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I want to write a middleware, which add a token to the header of the HttpClient.

here is my Program.cs

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
    builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7014") });

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocalStorage, LocalStorage>();

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Here is my middleware

```
// You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
public class AddTokenMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILocalStorage _localStorage;

    public AddTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,
        ILocalStorage localStorage)
    {
        _next = next;
        _localStorage = localStorage;
    }
    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var accessToken = _localStorage.GetStringAsync("token");
        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AddTokenMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

My questions are

1. How can I add my middleware to `Program.cs`?
2. How can I add `accessToken` to header of my httpClient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point of middleware is that you are intercepting an HTML request and fiddling with it before it gets run through the framework.  That's something you would do on server side.

Answer (score 2):

Blazor WebAssembly does not have the concept of middlewares, only blazor Server.

It would be best to add it to the HttpClient directly using DelegateHandler:

```
public class AuthDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string jwtToken = "YOUR_TOKEN";
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", jwtToken);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then use it with typed client:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<BackendClient>().AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthDelegatingHandler>();
```

Or named client:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("HTTP_CLIENT_NAME", x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7014")).AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthDelegatingHandler>();
```

Comment: What is the BackendClient in the code?

Comment: It's a "typed httpclient", I've updated the answer to use "named httpclient" which suits your case better.